# What XPath can I use to ignore certain parent element and access the value inside the child element?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML file. I need to access the `dataSource` element but skipping the `GetDecoders` element.

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://MultiChoice.CustomerCare.Service/ServiceContracts">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
     <ser:GetDecoders>
       <!--Optional:-->
        <ser:dataSource>Nigeria</ser:dataSource>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:packageName>SD</ser:packageName>
      </ser:GetDecoders>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried the following with no success:

```xml
/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='Body']/*/*[local-name()='dataSource' and text()='Nigeria']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try : `//ser:dataSource[.='Nigeria']` or

`//*[local-name()='dataSource'][.='Nigeria']`

Comment: Thanks I used //*[local-name()='dataSource'][.='Nigeria'] and it's working fine